# CrystalReportViewer deployment

Tags: crystal-reports

I created a VS 2008 C# MVC application which uses CrystalReportViewer to display a report. All the .dll files I used are either version 12.0.2000 or 12.0.1100.

The application works well on my localhost and the dev environment. 
When I deployed it (on a vista virtual machine with IIS 7.0) I ran two files :

1) CRRuntime_12_2_mlb.msi
2) CRRedist2008_x86.msi

Still when I open the viewer to view a report all I see is an empty view( the view only contains the CrystalReportViewer so obviously something is not working with the viewer on the deployment machine)

Can anyone give me clear steps on how to deploy a web app with CrystalReportViewer???
I looked around and could not find a clear instruictions.....just seems that everyone tries stuff until it works.

Thanks very much in advance

Susan

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem like above. Does somebody have a solution?

The web project using the following controls:

- CrystalReportSource (Version 12.0.2000.0)
- CrystalReportViewer (Version 12.0.2000.0)

On the server I have only installed CRRuntime_12_2_mlb.msi.

Best regards,

Daniel