# CrystalReportViewer not displaying in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm trying to display a `crystal report in a crystal report viewer in C# using Visual Studio 2005`, but the viewer object does not show the report while `"tempCover.Load"` can be executed.

It seems to be a problem related to this:
[CrystalReportViewer deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473814/crystalreportviewer-deployment?s=1|1.8282)

Is there any problem with my code? Many thanks.

```
public void PreviewReport() 
{
    ReportDocument tempCover = new ReportDocument();
    tempCover.Load(@"test.rpt");
    using (Form form = new Form()) 
    {
        writeLog("new form");
        CrystalReportViewer tempViewer = new CrystalReportViewer();
        tempViewer.ReportSource = tempCover;
        writeLog(Convert.ToString(tempViewer.ReportSource));
        tempViewer.AutoSize = true;
        tempViewer.Refresh();
        form.Controls.Add(tempViewer);
        form.AutoSize = true;
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}

log file

3:45:37 PM : new form
3:45:37 PM : CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
```

Comment: [Crystal Reports Tutorials MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227881(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully displayed the report after fixing the code as below.

```
public void PreviewReport() 
{
    ReportDocument tempCover = new ReportDocument();
    tempCover.Load(@"test.rpt");
    using (Form form = new Form()) 
    {
        writeLog("new form");
        CrystalReportViewer tempViewer = new CrystalReportViewer();

        tempViewer.ActiveViewIndex = -1;
        tempViewer.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        tempViewer.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        tempViewer.Name = "tempViewer";
        tempViewer.SelectionFormula = "";
        tempViewer.TabIndex = 0;
        tempViewer.ViewTimeSelectionFormula = "";

        tempViewer.ReportSource = tempCover;
        writeLog(Convert.ToString(tempViewer.ReportSource));
        tempViewer.AutoSize = true;
        tempViewer.Refresh();
        form.Controls.Add(tempViewer);
        form.AutoSize = true;
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```